# Why are mammals not very often (never?) toxic?

Tags: zoology

Often reptiles or insects have poison to defend themselves or to offend their prey. But I don't know any mammals which are toxic. So are there any mammals using poison and why aren't there so less/any?

Comment: The platypus has a venom, there's that.

Comment: A list of venomous mammals is available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_venomous_animals#Mammals. It could be worth noting that, although there are nine venomous mammal species listed amongst the ~5500 species of mammals, there are no venomous birds amongst the ~10000 species of birds, which makes avians an even more extreme group in this regard.

Comment: Note that "toxic" and "venomous" are not the same.  E.g. a rattlesnake is venomous but not toxic (you can eat it), while a puffer fish is toxic (you die if you eat it) but AFAIK not venomous.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the first part of your question: The [cuban solenodon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuban_solenodon) has venomous saliva. It's a mammal -- rather shrewlike in appearance. But yes, venomous mammals are rare!